# How to type function returning a class decorator? (python3.11)

Tags: python, generics, python-decorators, mypy

I know I can type a class decorator as follows:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Type[Any])
def decorator(cls: T) -> T:
    ...
```

Which can be used:

```
@decorator
class Foo:
   foo: int
```

And a reference to `foo` on instance of `Foo` will check properly in mypy.

But how do I type a function that returns a decorator, so that the decorated class types correctly? E.g. how can I fix the code below, if the arguments to `decorator`
have types not associated with the type of the wrapped class?

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Type[Any])
Decorator: TypeAlias = Callable[[T], T]

def decorator(...) -> Decorator[Any]:

    def wrapper(cls: T) -> T:
       # some code modifying cls depending on args to "decorator"
       ...
       return cls
    
    return wrapper

# now instance don't type write
@decorator(...)
class Foo:
    foo: int
```

Comment: It's your type alias to blame here: `mypy` isn't smart enough to bind a TypeVar inside `Callable` (you're trying to express that `__call__` method is generic, but not `Callable` itself - and `Callable` doesn't work this way). In such a simple case, just use `Callable[[T], T]` directly as a return type. If you need this in several places, @flakes protocol suggestion can be a better fit. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=01d62c44320c79b9c565acd95146f81b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the wrapper types become complex enough, I find that using `typing.Protocol` can be pretty useful. The function returned can be represented as non-generic class which supplies a generic `__call__` method.

```
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar('T', bound=t.Type[t.Any])


class Decorator(t.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, cls: T) -> T:
        ...


def decorator() -> Decorator:
    def wrapper(cls: T) -> T:
        # some code modifying cls depending on args to "decorator"
        ...
        return cls

    return wrapper


@decorator()
class Foo:
    foo: int


t.reveal_type(Foo)
t.assert_type(Foo(), Foo)
```

```
(venv) > mypy --strict main.py
main.py:25: note: Revealed type is "def () -> main.Foo"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Ah -- interesting! I guess the crucial detail here is that the Protocol itself *isn't* generic over T, so you can "delay binding" unlike the version with callable where the type var is at the "top level" and becomes "any". Thanks!